# How to use Node modules in the browser

Tags: arrays, node.js

I want to execute nodejs modules in the browser - on button click.

What is the best approach to execute nodejs module in the browser?

P.S I am running my web project on tomcat server.

Comment: They downvoted you just because you didn't use the _right_ terminology. They should remove the downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node is Javascript. Node modules are in Javascript.

If you want to use Node modules in the browser, you have two choices:

1. Visit the module's repo, some of them are already compatible with the browser OR have browser versions.

   - e.g. this one has a browser version: [bfred-it/image-promise](https://github.com/bfred-it/image-promise/tree/master/dist)
   - e.g. this one is already UMD (universal): [jonathantneal/svg4everybody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody/blob/master/dist/svg4everybody.js)
2. [Use browserify](https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-browserify/), this lets you use any Node module with just a little setup